# Netatalk Login problems with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, samba, afp

I have a problem with Netatalk and Active Directory. I can't login with an active directory user. Ive got already samba with ad connection working and i gets with wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g all data from AD.
Getent passwd shows me all users but i dont get ad groups with getent group.

Well i dont know if it would be a problem because i want to use only users instead of groups.

I've tested samba itself and i can connect a samba share with a active directory username.

At the moment, it seems it works "partialy". If i try to connect an afp volume with a known active directory user, i see in netatalk log following entries. Equally whether i type the right or wrong password:

```
Aug 10 08:48:37.908651 afpd[34123] {afp_dsi.c:624} (debug:AFPDaemon): <== Start AFP command: AFP_LOGINCONT
Aug 10 08:48:37.919318 afpd[34123] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:214} (info:UAMS): PAM DHX2: PAM Success
Aug 10 08:48:40.121785 afpd[34123] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:666} (info:UAMS): DHX2: PAM_Error: Authentication failure
Aug 10 08:48:40.121848 afpd[34123] {dsi_cmdreply.c:24} (debug:DSI): dsi_cmdreply(DSI ID: 4, len: 0): START
Aug 10 08:48:40.121883 afpd[34123] {dsi_stream.c:530} (maxdebug:DSI): dsi_stream_send(0 bytes): START
```

If i type a invalid user i've got a different error:

```
Aug 10 08:55:16.416783 afpd[34205] {afp_dsi.c:624} (debug:AFPDaemon): <== Start AFP command: AFP_LOGIN_EXT
Aug 10 08:55:18.830640 afpd[34205] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:324} (info:UAMS): DHX2: unknown username
Aug 10 08:55:18.830711 afpd[34205] {dsi_cmdreply.c:24} (debug:DSI): dsi_cmdreply(DSI ID: 2, len: 0): START
Aug 10 08:55:18.830732 afpd[34205] {dsi_stream.c:530} (maxdebug:DSI): dsi_stream_send(0 bytes): START
Aug 10 08:55:18.830745 afpd[34205] {dsi_stream.c:538} (maxdebug:DSI): dsi_stream_send(16 bytes): DSI header, no data
Aug 10 08:55:18.830762 afpd[34205] {dsi_stream.c:281} (maxdebug:DSI): dsi_stream_write(send: 16 bytes): START
```

I've watches also the logs from samba/winbind and it seems there are only queries if the user is not known. If i typ a valid user, the logs in samba and winbind are still quite.

Well im also wondering the kerberos module uam_gss.so seems also dont work:

```
Aug 10 09:34:09.480536 afpd[45001] {auth.c:1011} (debug:AFPDaemon): 
auth_load: /usr/local/lib/netatalk//, uam_gss.so,uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2.so
Aug 10 09:34:09.480562 afpd[45001] {auth.c:1025} (debug:AFPDaemon): uam: loading (/usr/local/lib/netatalk//uam_gss.so)
Aug 10 09:34:09.480577 afpd[45001] {auth.c:1037} (info:AFPDaemon): uam: uam not found (status=-1)
Aug 10 09:34:09.480585 afpd[45001] {auth.c:1025} (debug:AFPDaemon): uam: loading (/usr/local/lib/netatalk//uams_dhx.so)
Aug 10 09:34:09.518932 afpd[45001] {auth.c:1032} (debug:AFPDaemon): uam: uams_dhx.so loaded
Aug 10 09:34:09.518975 afpd[45001] {auth.c:1025} (debug:AFPDaemon): uam: loading (/usr/local/lib/netatalk//uams_dhx2.so)
Aug 10 09:34:09.519205 afpd[45001] {uams_dhx2_pam.c:934} (debug:UAMS): DHX2: generating mersenne primes
Aug 10 09:34:09.712308 afpd[45001] {auth.c:1032} (debug:AFPDaemon): uam: uams_dhx2.so loaded
```

I spend days of searching but there is no solution in sight. Ive already found various how to's but it didnt work for me. For example from netatalk officialy: http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/How-To_authenticate_to_an_NT_domain

Maybe it could works with Kerberos but i didnt get the module working...

Here are some background informations:

I use a Ubuntu 16.04 on a DELL R420. The Active Directory based on a Windows Server 2012 R2 enviroment. I use Samba version 4.3.9-Ubuntu and Winbind 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.

I've compiled already the recent Netatalk version 3.1.9 with all features. I used following lines to compile:

```
./configure --with-init-style=debian-systemd \
 --with-cracklib --enable-pgp-uam --enable-krbV-uam \
 --with-pam-confdir=/etc/pam.d \
 --with-dbus-sysconf-dir=/etc/dbus-1/system.d \
 --with-tracker-pkgconfig-version=1.0
```

Compilation summary:

```
    CPPFLAGS       = -I$(top_srcdir)/include -I$(top_builddir)/include -I$(top_srcdir)
    CFLAGS         = -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -g -O2
    LIBS           =  -lcrack
    PTHREADS:
        LIBS   =
        CFLAGS = -pthread
    TRACKER:
        LIBS   = -ltracker-sparql-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -Wl,--export-dynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0
        CFLAGS = -pthread -I/usr/include/tracker-1.0 -I/usr/include/tracker-1.0/libtracker-sparql -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
    SSL:
        LIBS   =  -L/usr/lib64 -lcrypto
        CFLAGS =  -I/usr/include/openssl
    LIBGCRYPT:
        LIBS   = -lgcrypt
        CFLAGS =
    PAM:
        LIBS   =  -lpam
        CFLAGS =
    WRAP:
        LIBS   = -lwrap
        CFLAGS =
    BDB:
        LIBS   =  -L/usr/lib64 -ldb-5.3
        CFLAGS =
    GSSAPI:
        LIBS   = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err
        CFLAGS = -isystem /usr/include/mit-krb5
    ZEROCONF:
        LIBS   =  -lavahi-common -lavahi-client
        CFLAGS =  -D_REENTRANT
    LDAP:
        LIBS   =  -lldap
        CFLAGS =
    LIBEVENT:
        bundled
    TDB:
        bundled
    MySQL:
        LIBS   = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl
        CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/mysql -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
Configure summary:
    INIT STYLE:
         debian-systemd
    AFP:
         Extended Attributes: ad | sys
         ACL support: yes
         Spotlight: yes
    CNID:
         backends:  dbd last tdb mysql
    UAMS:
         DHX     (PAM SHADOW)
         DHX2    (PAM SHADOW)
         RANDNUM (afppasswd)
         Kerberos V
         PGP
         clrtxt  (PAM SHADOW)
         guest
    Options:
         Zeroconf support:        yes
         tcp wrapper support:     yes
         quota support:           yes
         valid shell check:       yes
         cracklib support:        yes
         ACL support:             auto
         Kerberos support:        yes
         LDAP support:            yes
         AFP stats via dbus:      yes
         dtrace probes:           yes
    Paths:
         Netatalk lockfile:       /var/lock/netatalk
         init directory:          /lib/systemd/system
         dbus system directory:   /etc/dbus-1/system.d
         dbus daemon path:        /bin/dbus-daemon
         tracker prefix:          /usr
         tracker install prefix:  /usr
         tracker manager:         /usr/bin/tracker daemon
         pam config directory:    /etc/pam.d
    Documentation:
         Docbook:                 no
```

Here is my netatalk configuration:

```
[Global]
k5 keytab    = /etc/krb5.keytab
uam list     = uam_gss.so,uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2.so

nt domain    = AD.DOMAIN.LOCAL
ad domain    = AD.DOMAIN.LOCAL
map acls     = rights

ldap server      = ad.domain.local
ldap auth method = simple
ldap auth dn     = CN=ldapinfo,OU=IT,OU=Services,OU=Intern,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=local
ldap auth pw     = ************
ldap userbase    = OU=Staff,OU=company,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=local
ldap userscope   = sub
ldap groupbase   = OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=local
ldap groupscope  = sub
ldap uuid attr   = objectGUID
ldap name attr   = sAMAccountName
ldap group attr  = cn


; Global server settings
hostname = TimeMachine.domain.local
vol preset = default_for_all
log file = /var/log/netatalk.log
log level = default:maxdebug

save password = no
afpstats = yes


[default_for_all]
file perm = 0664
directory perm = 0774
cnid scheme = dbd
; Uncomment the following line to restrict access to specific users
; valid users = someuser

# [Homes]
# basedir regex = /storage/timemachine
# time machine = yes
# vol size limit = 102400
#

# Config for time machine users
include = /usr/local/etc/afp_users.conf
```

afp_users.conf

```
[test1]
name = Timemachine
time machine = yes
vol size limit = 102400
path = /storage/timemachine/test1
valid users = test1
```

/etc/pam.d/netatalk

```
#%PAM-1.0
# Following lines dont work
#auth       required     pam_winbind.so
#account    required     pam_winbind.so
#session    required     pam_unix.so

auth     include common-auth
account  include common-account
password include common-password
session  include common-session
```

Samba Config:

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
        netbios name = CLIENT1
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        security = ADS
        realm = AD.DOMAIN.LOCAL
        dedicated keytab file = /etc/krb5.keytab
        kerberos method = secrets and keytab

        idmap config *:backend = tdb
        idmap config *:range = 2000-50000
        idmap config SAMDOM:backend = ad
        idmap config SAMDOM:range   = 50001 - 99999
        idmap config SAMDOM:schema_mode = rfc2307

        winbind nss info = rfc2307
        #passdb backend = pam
        winbind trusted domains only = no
        winbind use default domain = yes
        winbind enum users  = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        winbind nested groups = yes
        winbind refresh tickets = Yes
        obey pam restrictions = no

        template homedir = /storage/timemachine/%U
        template shell = /bin/bash

        #encrypt passwords = no

        hide dot files = no

#### Debugging/Accounting ####

    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    log level = 10


# ####### Authentication #######
#    server role = standalone server
#    passdb backend = tdbsam
#    obey pam restrictions = yes
#    unix password sync = yes
#
#    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
#    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
#
#    pam password change = yes
#    map to guest = bad user
#
# ########## Domains ###########


[TEST]
        path = /storage/test
        valid users = testuser
        read only = no
        create mask = 0666
        directory mask = 0777
        acl map full control = True
        force user = nobody
        force group = nogroup
        guest ok =  yes
```

I would be happy if someone have an idea. Thank you

Comment: So, i build up a vm with ubuntu 14.04 and i tried again. Well, it works... i've done the same configuration like before. But this time i used the source on git. The actual version is 3.1.10dev. Well, i've tried to update Netatalk to the same version but it didnt work for me. I have no doubt why it seems do not work on ubuntu 16.04. I start now a dstribution update to 16.04 on my virtual machine and i test it again. If it doesn't work again, so i have to use Ubuntu 14.04 for Netatalk....

Comment: That is crazy... I've done the update to 16.04 on my test VM. After recompile Netatalk, it still works. I have no clue about what i did could make wrong. The configuration seems to be fine... So i will purge my live system and i try it again.

Comment: So, ive finished the reinstallation of the live system with ubuntu 16.04 now. Im happy because netatalk works as expected now. After clean reinstallation i can login with any domain accounts on my afp volumes.